# Index in Stage Area Database

Tags: database, etl, data-warehouse

I'm building a stage area database, and occurred me the question, if is relevant to create indexes at stage area database.

It's this a best practice?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

typically the tables in the stage area database will not have indexes. The only common exception is adding indexes after the the load to help with the transformations.

Comment: Depending on your RDBMS, your ETL package should either drop and recreate the indices or disable and then rebuild them.